# Node,js Web Scrape -> Large Payload Issues -> "socket hang up"

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, node-modules, large-data

I have a working web scraper however when I run it on a large batch of urls I end up getting the below error periodically.

```
"FetchError: request to "URL"  failed, reason: socket hang up"
```

Lets say out of 3000 urls I will catch about 4-6 of these errors.

I have done extensive troubleshooting on this but cannot seem to make it run smoothly. The URL's are valid, and I receive the `ECONNRESET` timeouts which leads me to believe that because of volume of requests to the server it is a result of a slow network response. If I were to go back and run it on just these 4-6 URLS I would correctly scrape them.

I have made several adjustments but my main approached are below and on my fetch:

```
{signal: AbortSignal.timeout(3000)}

And:

{
    retries: 3,
    retryDelay: 1000
  }
```

Below is the relevant code block. I can could post more of the script but since it is somewhat working I hope this is all that is needed.

```
                try {
                    await fetch(line)

                        .then(res => {
                            if (res.ok && res.status === 200) {
                                const dest = fs.createWriteStream(OUTPUT_DIR + parent_path + updated_filename)
                                if (!fs.existsSync(OUTPUT_DIR + parent_path + updated_filename)) {
                                    res.body.pipe(dest);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("File Already Exists");
                                }

                            } else {
                                console.log("There was an issue with the URL");
                            }
                        });

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    errors.write(line + "\r\n");
                }
```

Any help or insight would be great. Maybe I am thinking about or using the AbortSignal or retrys incorrectly, or maybe I need do something to the urls I'm passing to the fetch.
Again this always works on small batches, it's the large batches where I run into this trouble. I also see this is a someone common issue, but I have yet to come across a solution that worked in my case.

Comment: When reusing HTTP / HTTP sockets you often encounter this issue, or when you have a response or request where the other party closes the connection for various reasons.

When you encounter an error you can perform a fast retry (in case the server just cut you off due to the socket needing to be closed) and then an exponential backoff for further retries (in case the server is overloaded).

Comment: @CodyＧ 
So something along the lines of this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry
Will try and let you know. TY.